# Dynamic casting to different derived class through same interface

Tags: c++, c++17

Let say I want to parse and evaluate these expression

```
a = 5;
b = 25.0;
c = a + b;
```

Its C++ equivalent is

```cpp
int a = 5;
double b = 25.0;
double c = a + b;
```

`a`, `b` and `c` are `Symbol` and during parsing, will be registered to `SymbolTable`.

```cpp
enum class Type { int_t, real_t };

struct Symbol {
    bool evaluated = false;
    Type type;  // int or real enum
    Symbol(bool eval, Type t) : evaluated(eval), type(t) {}
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Symbol>> parameters;
    virtual Symbol* getp() = 0;
};

struct IntSymbol : Symbol {
    int value;
    IntSymbol() : Symbol(false, Type::int_t) {}
    IntSymbol(int val) : Symbol(true, Type::int_t), value(val) {}
    int getVal() const { return value; }
    virtual IntSymbol* getp() override { return this; }
};

struct RealSymbol : Symbol {
    double value;
    RealSymbol() : Symbol(false, Type::real_t) {}
    RealSymbol(double val) : Symbol(true, Type::real_t), value(val) {}
    double getVal() const { return value; }
    virtual RealSymbol* getp() override { return this; }
};

struct SymbolTable {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Symbol>> table;
    void insert(std::string a, std::shared_ptr<Symbol> b) {
        table.insert({a, b});
    }
    std::shared_ptr<Symbol> get(std::string a) { return table.at(a); }
};
```

The values of `a` and `b` are already known but `c` is unknown. So, the `Symbol` will be created like below.
`Symbol c` will contain a list of pointers to its parameters.

```cpp
SymbolTable table;
auto createSymbolandRegister = [&]() {
   auto a = std::make_shared<IntSymbol>(5);
   auto b = std::make_shared<RealSymbol>(25.0);
   // value not known yet.
   auto c = std::make_shared<RealSymbol>();
   // pointer to its parameters
   c->parameters = {a, b};
   table.insert("a", a);
   table.insert("b", b);
   table.insert("c", c);
};
createSymbolandRegister();
```

For evaluating `c`, I create a LLVM IR and JIT compile it to get function definition

```cpp
// Here `func` is corresponding function that should be called to evaluate `c`.
double func(int, double);
```

To evaluate, I want to do this.

```cpp
    // there is already some mapping informing that when `c` needs to be evaluated `func`
    // should be called. 
    // Now, to evaluate c, get its symbol from table.
    auto val = table.get("c");
    switch(val->type)
    {
        case Type::int_t:
            //... do int op.
            break;
        case Type::real_t:
            RealSymbol* c = dynamic_cast<RealSymbol*>(c);
            // How to dynamic cast to correct type based on enum Type info? Dervied type is only known through enum.
            auto* ca = getCorrectDerivedType(a); 
            auto* cb = getCorrectDerivedType(b);

            c->value = func(ca->value, cb->value);
    }
```

My problem is: I need to dynamic cast the `Symbol` stored in `parameters` to correct derived type when dervied type is only known through enum?  I will not be able to `switch` using enum as the result of dynamic cast must be passed to the function.

```cpp
auto* ca = getCorrectDerivedType(a);
auto* cb = getCorrectDerivedType(b);
```

Is there any way to `dynamic_cast` to different derived class through same interface?

Another idea was to use `std::variant<int, double>` in place of polymorphic class. But, I couldn't find a possible way to extract correct type and value based on runtime information for the call to `func`.

CodeLink:
https://godbolt.org/z/d9zaf8e45

Edit 1:

The generated function is not a valid "C++" function. JIT compiler gives only an address to the function in the memory. I will know the function definition because I parsed the expression and did the type resolution.

So, only at runtime, I will know that the generated function will look like
`double func(int, double)` and definition looks like this

```cpp
auto address = some_address_given_by_jit_compiler;
auto* func = (double)(*)(...)address;
```

Comment: From `func`, you know you should have `int`, then `double`, so a `virtual evaluateAsInt();virtual evaluateAsDouble();` seems a possible option.

Comment: If you’re *generating* `f` anyway, you could make it take `Symbol` arguments and do the casting itself.

Comment: @Jarod42 Do you mean like this https://godbolt.org/z/14fWW89qz. It works only as long as I have two types. How can it be extended to multiple types?

Comment: @DavisHerring I can. But, I want it to be the last option.

Comment: @aneax: Not in that sense. You have `double func(int, double);`, so `func(param0.asInt(), param1.AsDouble())`. I don't cast depending of real type of `param0`, but depending of its usage (which might indeed not match).

Comment: @Jarod42 That's the exact problem, I will not know which one should I call `param0.asInt()` or `param0.asDouble()`  for first parameter unless I look at the `param0.type`.

Comment: Do you have `double func(int, double);` or not? If you have, first parameter is an `int`...

Comment: @Jarod42 I parse the expression, create a LLVM IR and JIT compile it to get function definition `double func(int, double)` at runtime. So, yes, I have `double func(int,double)` but is created at runtime.

Comment: So rename `asInt` with `operator int()` and call `func(*ca, *cb);`?

Comment: Yes. It will work if the generated function `func` is C++ function (C++ frontend compiled). But,  it is not.  So, any of the overload resolution things will not work with `func`. I have to manually make sure the correct type is passed to the function. I have added more information up.

Comment: @aneax: I would say that you made a mistake when you decided to put the type information about a symbol as part of the symbol's *type* instead of storing it as a *value* within the `Symbol` class.